# Apache 2 error log only shows the error message "0"

Tags: apache, apache2, error-log

Since a few days, my Apache 2 error log is showing a lot messages like the following (IP addresses and URIs redacted):

```
[Thu Dec 12 13:46:42 2013] [error] [client 111.222.333.444] 0
[Thu Dec 12 13:52:27 2013] [error] [client 222.333.444.555] 0, referer: http://www.mydomain.com/
[Thu Dec 12 13:52:27 2013] [error] [client 222.333.444.555] 0, referer: http://www.mydomain.com/
[Thu Dec 12 13:53:54 2013] [error] [client 333.444.555.666] 0, referer: http://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory/
[Thu Dec 12 13:46:42 2013] [error] [client 444.555.666.777] 0
[Thu Dec 12 13:54:07 2013] [error] [client aaaa:1111:2222:ffff::] 0, referer: http://www.otherdomain.com/subdirectory/
```

What is this `0`? There are no other messages shown (besides sometimes some other, normal messages, but very rarely).

The IP addresses are both IPv4 and IPv6. I checked the access log for the same date/time and IP addresses. Most of the times, there was an access for the exact same moment from this IP for different URIs on my webpage. But sometimes, there wasn't an access according to the access log.

It's a shared hosting environment, so I can't access the Apache settings (but I have ssh access to my home directory if this helps). I already googled and searched the Apache documentation, but didn't found anything (it's hard to search for "0"...)

/edit: I also asked the webhoster, they said they don't know what it's causing. I cross checked it with the Apache access log, these are requests to PHP scripts (mostly Joomla), but also requests to images as well as JS and CSS files. So I assume it's not a PHP script which is causing this.

Comment: Are there any .htaccess files that may have the `LogFormat` directive specified?

Comment: Not from me. Maybe the hoster added something in the httpd.conf but in this case the hoster would know and could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your error_log directive is unset errors will be written in your Apache log file for current VirtualHost.
So double check your [PHP configuration (php.ini)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) or write a simple page with [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

If this is true, you should look inside your code (may be even into index.php).

Pay attention to this: usually there are two separate php.ini files for Apache `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and CLI configuration `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

Please also consider that, if you want change your PHP configuration, you can use [ini_set function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

```
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/php/error_new.log');
```

Remember: the destination directory must exist and your web server (or php engine) must have all permission to write into.

Comment: I don't have access to php.ini because it's a shared hosting environment, but phpinfo() states `no value` for `error_log`. In the admin console I can configure if PHP's errors should be written into Apache's error_log and it's set to "on". I never saw this before... I'll change it to "off" and monitor Apache's error log.

Comment: But when I compare the access times of the error log with the access log, sometimes there aren't any accesses in the second the error gets logged. I didn't thought these PHP scripts run longer than a second

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please consider the ini_set suggestion. You can change PHP error_log into your web app main configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I added `ini_set('error_log', '...');` to the main PHP script and now the `0`'s get logged to this file. Now I have to search for the main reason, but at least I know it's Joomla, not Apache.

Answer (score 1):

error_log format is not customizable, I suspect that it can be set to some higher level: debug or trace, where it can produce additional information.

Also please take into account, that error_log contains debug info from CGI/PHP/Perl scripts, so that 'zero' can be produced by some script that executed through apache as its module.

Comment: According to the access.log, several PHP scripts are called when the error occures. Sometimes it's Joomla, sometimes one of my own scripts, sometimes even only images/CSS/JS files. So I doubt it's some of my scripts causing this. I still assume the hoster did something to the config.

Comment: please re-read my reply carefully, error_log is not customizable until your hoster is using apache webserver, if its nginx or anything else, then it can be different. If you want to findout the root cause of that messages, then you need root access to server there apache is running, and `strace` httpd processes when this messages occurs.  But most probably 0 - is an error return code or message from some php script function.

Comment: I understood your answer. My reply refered to your second paragraph. It's not one PHP script which is called, it's PHP, images, CSS... Unfortunately, I don't have root access, so I can't check the httpd processes.

Comment: at least, you can ask your hoster support team for that task.